# Error while encrypting password

Tags: data-loader, encryption, commandline

I am trying to encrypt the password using command

`encrypt -e mypassword "D:\SFDC_docs\Salesforce-connectivity\try\Key.txt"`

but getting error as

> " security.EncryptionUtil main (EncryptionUtil.java:289) - Invalid
>   option format: ûe".

I need this to use command line data loader. Please help. Please dont mark it as duplicate as the solutions given in other threads are not working for me.

Comment: It looks like you `mypassword` string contains characters that the cmd.exe is interpreting as option strings. First thing to try is to add double quotes i.e. try `"mypassword"`. Or change your password and stick to simple alphanumerics (and make your password longer to compensate security-wise).

Comment: try removing dash "-" in front of "-e" and inserting minus instead. If you copy/pasted this from some document then dash in "-e" may not be the "minus" character you think it is. Just remove the whole "-e" thing and type it again.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you copy pasted command `encrypt.bat -e "C:\temp\key.txt"` from some website.

It should be minus sign instead of dash, Can you try to type it and run it. You may find some helping steps [here](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/tutorial-of-command-line-dataloader-salesforce/) as well.

Comment: Um, what is the difference between minus sign and dash?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must write "encrypt.bat" with extension instead of only "encrypt".

Hope this may help.

Comment: I tried as encrypt.bat -e rrpatil228 "D:\SFDC_docs\Salesforce-FTP_connectivity\try\Key.txt"   as well, but giving same error

Comment: ok, try adding your security token after your pwd : rrpatil228SECURITYTOKEN